# Filling in dates using SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to query a data set where I can get a full count of status on a given set of days.  The data would look like this

```
Customer ID   Status     Date
1             pending    2020-01-01
1             shipped    2020-01-04
1             delivered  2020-01-06
```

The problem is the status needs to carry over to each of the preceding days so I can sum all status' at the end.  So in a perfect world the data would look like this

```
Customer ID    Status    Date
1              pending   2020-01-01
1              pending   2020-01-02
1              pending   2020-01-03
1              shipped   2020-01-04
1              shipped   2020-01-05
1              delivered 2020-01-06
```

This would allow me to sum the data set appropriately at the end of the query.  I have a table of dates I can join to, but I am struggling to figure out how to fill in the dates that fall between the status changes.

Thanks

Comment: I have a sql server solution for you please check and let me know.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are quite product specific Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You have the dates table then you need to use `lead` analytical function join it as follows:

```
Select t.customerid, t.status, d.date
  From (select lead(date) over (partition by customerid order by date) as ldate from your_table t) t
  Join date_table d
    On (d.date >= t.date and d.date < t.ldate) 
    or (t.ldate is null and t.date = d.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you in SQL Server. Please check the query.

```
DECLARE @CustomerInfo TABLE 
(
    CustomerID INT,
    [Status] VARCHAR(50),
    StatusDate DATE
);

DECLARE @FinalCustomerInfo TABLE 
(
    CustomerID INT,
    [Status] VARCHAR(50),
    StatusDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO @CustomerInfo VALUES(1, 'pending' ,CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE));
INSERT INTO @CustomerInfo VALUES(1, 'shipped ' ,CAST('2020-01-04 ' AS DATE));
INSERT INTO @CustomerInfo VALUES(1, 'delivered' ,CAST('2020-01-06' AS DATE));

DECLARE @startpending_date DATETIME;
DECLARE @endpending_date DATETIME;
DECLARE @startshipped_date DATETIME;
DECLARE @endshipped_date DATETIME;

SET @startpending_date=(select top 1 StatusDate  from @CustomerInfo Where [Status]='pending');
SET @endpending_date=  DATEADD(DAY, -1, (select top 1 StatusDate  from @CustomerInfo Where [Status]='shipped'));

WITH    AllDays
 AS ( SELECT   @startpending_date AS [Date], 1 AS [level], 'pending' [Status]
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]), [level] + 1 ,'pending' [Status]
               FROM     AllDays
               WHERE    [Date] <  @endpending_date )
     INSERT INTO @FinalCustomerInfo
     SELECT ci.CustomerID,ci.Status,ad.Date StatusDate
     FROM   AllDays  ad
     LEFT JOIN @CustomerInfo ci ON ad.[Status]=ci.[Status]

SET @startshipped_date=(select top 1 StatusDate  from @CustomerInfo Where [Status]='shipped');
SET @endshipped_date=  DATEADD(DAY, -1, (select top 1 StatusDate  from @CustomerInfo Where [Status]='delivered'));

WITH    AllDays
 AS ( SELECT   @startshipped_date AS [Date], 1 AS [level], 'shipped' [Status]
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]), [level] + 1 ,'shipped' [Status]
               FROM     AllDays
               WHERE    [Date] <  @endshipped_date )
     INSERT INTO @FinalCustomerInfo
     SELECT ci.CustomerID,ci.Status,ad.Date StatusDate
     FROM   AllDays  ad
     LEFT JOIN @CustomerInfo ci ON ad.[Status]=ci.[Status]

INSERT INTO @FinalCustomerInfo
SELECT * FROM @CustomerInfo Where [Status]='delivered';

SELECT * FROM @FinalCustomerInfo;
```

**Note:** To find date range I have used a window function. My Query is written in sql server it might not work in other sql platforms.
The Query shows exact output what you desire for. Please let me know it works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by below query (though it can be more optimized I think):

```
create table S65856043CustomerStatus(CustomerID int, Status varchar(20), Dates date)

insert into S65856043CustomerStatus values (1, 'pending', '2020-01-01')
insert into S65856043CustomerStatus values (1, 'shipped', '2020-01-04')
insert into S65856043CustomerStatus values (1, 'delivered', '2020-01-06')

with dateRange as 
(
    select min(dates) mn, max(dates) mx 
    from S65856043CustomerStatus
),
calendar as
(
    select dateadd(day, nbr - 1, mn) Days
    from 
        (select distinct nbr = number 
         from master..[spt_values], daterange
         where number between 1 and datediff(day, mn, mx) + 1
        ) nbrs, dateRange
    where nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(DAY, mn, mx)
),
t as
(
    select 
        days, CustomerID, status, dates, 
        count(status) over (order by days) val2
    from 
        calendar 
    left join 
        S65856043CustomerStatus on days = dates
)
select 
    max(customerid) over (partition by val2) customerid,
    days dates,
    max(status) over (partition by val2) status 
from 
    t
```